# PHP run same script at the same time

Tags: php, shell

So I am trying to run in the shell the same script with different parameters.

```
for ($x = 0; $x < count($tests); $x++) {
    $plug = fopen('includes/test.txt', 'w');
    fputs($plug, $tests[$x]);
    fclose($plug);
    shell_exec("php test.sp > /dev/null &");
}
```

Test.sp gets the params from test.txt and runs a script. I want to start with 10 different params at the same time.
But it only starts with the last param of $tests.

Can I ask you guys how to change it to work?

Comment: How does test.php get the parameters from test.txt? Show the relevant code. Are you aware that the "w" flag will truncate the file being opened? Using this in a loop will result in the file's contents being overwritten in every iteration.

Comment: $plug = fopen('includes/test.txt', 'r');
$plugins[] = fgets($plug);
fclose($plug);
This is how I get the content of the txt file in test.php

Comment: If you want to pass the value of `$tests[$x]` to test.php, why not pass it as cmd arg? `shell_exec("test.php " . $tests[$x] . " > /dev/null &")`

Comment: This worked! Thank you.